# didUpdateLocations Implementation of speedometer

Tags: swift, core-location

I'm diving into Swift, creating simple app to get current speed, ala speedometer.

Here is my implementation of didUpdateLocations.

Is it correct logic?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    speed = (locations.last?.speed ?? 0.0) * 3.6
    speedLabel.text = "\(Int(speed) ?? 0)"

    maxSpeed = getMaxSpeed(maxSpeed,two: (speed))
    maxSpeedLabel.text = "\(Int(maxSpeed) ?? 0)"

    print ("\(speed) km/h and max speed \(maxSpeed) km/h")
```

}

On simulator It works great, but I'm not shure that values on screen are correct.

Comment: That seems ok, it's [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed) as m/s and your conversion factor to km/h (60 * 60 / 1000) is accurate. Why do you think it might be wrong? Have you done any testing?

Comment: I'd like to be confident that It's correct. So Thanx much!

Comment: What values do you see, and what values are you expecting to see? Are you only testing this with the simulator, or have you tried it in the real world traveling at a known speed to compare it to? Did you try it outdoors, or indoors? What is the accuracy of the location manager?

Comment: Hop in a car as a passenger and go for a drive?

Comment: I tried in real word, something wrong, speed of my car was about 80 Km/h, but on screen of my app was about 20 

I set accuracy of GPS - kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

I even don't know what's problem